# Zero-argument constructor issue in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a very simple program in Kotlin just to try to get used to it.  It will build in Android Studio with zero issues, and then return fatal error on the device:

```
package com.example.check_in

import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.util.Log
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import java.util.Date


class SmsTracker(context: Context) : ContextWrapper(context) {
   private val appContext: Context = applicationContext
   private val contentResolver: ContentResolver = appContext.contentResolver
   private var cursor: Cursor? = null
```

This returns the following error with the Android phone connected by USB:

> PROCESS STARTED (26298) for package com.example.check_in
> ---------------------------- 2023-06-19 08:32:01.099 26298-26298 xample.check_in         com.example.check_in                 W
> Redefining intrinsic method java.lang.Thread
> java.lang.Thread.currentThread(). This may cause the unexpected use of
> the original definition of java.lang.Thread
> java.lang.Thread.currentThread()in methods that have already been
> compiled. 2023-06-19 08:32:01.099 26298-26298 xample.check_in
> com.example.check_in                 W  Redefining intrinsic method
> boolean java.lang.Thread.interrupted(). This may cause the unexpected
> use of the original definition of boolean
> java.lang.Thread.interrupted()in methods that have already been
> compiled. 2023-06-19 08:32:01.102 26298-26298 Compatibil...geReporter
> com.example.check_in                 D  Compat change id reported:
> 171979766; UID 10374; state: ENABLED 2023-06-19 08:32:01.110
> 26298-26298 ziparchive              com.example.check_in
> W  Unable to open
> '/data/data/com.example.check_in/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dm':
> No such file or directory 2023-06-19 08:32:01.112 26298-26298
> xample.check_in         com.example.check_in                 W
> ClassLoaderContext classpath size mismatch. expected=0, found=1 (PCL[]
> |
> PCL[/data/data/com.example.check_in/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex*222021406])
> 2023-06-19 08:32:01.119 26298-26298 nativeloader
> com.example.check_in                 D  Configuring
> classloader-namespace for other apk
> /data/app/~~CFRupp1tiaLh-cqxRJlzeg==/com.example.check_in-3kRsT7WaNyILayLaLSV99Q==/base.apk.
> target_sdk_version=33, uses_libraries=,
> library_path=/data/app/~~CFRupp1tiaLh-cqxRJlzeg==/com.example.check_in-3kRsT7WaNyILayLaLSV99Q==/lib/arm64,
> permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.check_in
> 2023-06-19 08:32:01.126 26298-26298 GraphicsEnvironment
> com.example.check_in                 V  ANGLE Developer option for
> 'com.example.check_in' set to: 'default' 2023-06-19 08:32:01.126
> 26298-26298 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.check_in
> V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.check_in: false 2023-06-19
> 08:32:01.126 26298-26298 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.check_in
> V  App is not on the allowlist for updatable production driver.
> 2023-06-19 08:32:01.128 26298-26298 NetworkSecurityConfig
> com.example.check_in                 D  No Network Security Config
> specified, using platform default 2023-06-19 08:32:01.133 26298-26298
> NetworkSecurityConfig   com.example.check_in                 D  No
> Network Security Config specified, using platform default 2023-06-19
> 08:32:01.139 26298-26330 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.check_in
> D  RenderThread::requireGlContext() 2023-06-19 08:32:01.140
> 26298-26298 AndroidRuntime          com.example.check_in
> D  Shutting down VM 2023-06-19 08:32:01.140 26298-26298 AndroidRuntime
> com.example.check_in                 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.check_in, PID: 26298
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.check_in/com.example.check_in.SmsTracker}:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.check_in.SmsTracker> has no zero argument
> constructor
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4051)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4315)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8747)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.check_in.SmsTracker> has no zero argument
> constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at
> android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
> at
> androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1328)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4038)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4315) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8747) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
> 2023-06-19 08:32:01.140 26298-26330 AdrenoGLES-0
> com.example.check_in                 I  QUALCOMM build
> : 9ab6a2b2d8, Ifc633ebcef
> Build Date                       : 01/24/23

I've tried to enter in something like this:

```
class SmsTracker(context: Context) : ContextWrapper(context) {
    constructor() : this(ApplicationContextProvider.context)
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? And what is the reason for extending ContextWrapper? It is very unusual in my opinion to need to create your own Context class. I've never seen it done in the 12 years I've been developing for Android.

Comment: Why do you need to extends this class from `ContextWrapper` ?  You should.t do this ContextWrapper component initialized by the System itself thats the same reason you do not have a single parameterized constructor inside an `Activity` .. If you need context inside this class just inject it inside constructor that's all .

Comment: Sorry, I added the error information.  Keep in mind that I've never programmed in Kotlin before - I haven't touched code for something like 20 years -- all the way back to ASP classic.

Comment: You'e doing something that's causing the system to initialize a SmsTracker object, but it can't do it because it's assuming that the class will have a construtor that takes no arguments.  We have no idea why the system is trying to make it, because you didn't post where this class was used or the whole stack trace of the crash.

Comment: OK, I've tried to add the stack trace up to the error by editing the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to extend the `ContextWrapper` class. The following should work just fine:

```kotlin
class SmsTracker(context: Context) {
   private val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver
   private var cursor: Cursor? = null
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android app, you start with `Activity`. My guess is that you've configured `<activity android:name=` in your Manifest to point to your `SmsTracker` class.

You must create a class that derives from `Activity` (preferrably `AppCompatActivity`). This class cannot have any ctor parameters because it's instantiated by the system, and there's no way to tell the system to pass some values there.

That's unrelated to Kotlin.

Comment: Thanks @Agent_L
So I need to put this into import statements:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Zman You should really try projects generated by the Android Studio when you select "new". Some of them are too simple, others are too complicated - but they will give you a generic idea on what's important.

Comment: @Zman Also, if you know Java (or C, or C#), then start in Java, get a hold how Android works and then use "convert to Kotlin"